# How to only allow some inputs: python

Tags: python, input

I am trying to only allow some input in python using the following code

```
while True:
    age=input('Are you 1,2 OR 3')
    if age== ('1' or '2' or '3'):
        break
    else:
        print('df')
```

When I enter 1, no error comes up and it continues to the rest of the programme, however when I enter 2 or 3, it comes up with the else: error. I've tried changing it round a bit and it seems as though it only accepts the first number from the choices (1).
Probably a very simple fix. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've closed as the dupe that I think you're ultimately asking for (type conversion and 2.x/3.x checking etc...)... but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values as to how to correctly test against multiple values in general

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `age` checking with:

```
if age in ('1', '2', '3'):
```

`'1' or '2' or '3'` is a boolean expression that returns the first non empty string. And in this case the string is `'1'`.

For example:

```
>>> '1' or '2' or '3'
'1'
>>> '' or '2' or '3'
'2'
```

Comment: @aruisdante, `True` is not the chained `or` result as shown above. Also, from the syntax the OP is probably using Python 3, so `input` would be returning a string.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, didn't think that one through all the way ;) Though nothing syntactically there screams 3, function-print is in 2.7. But yes, given that the chained `or` would in fact return `'1'`, almost certainly 3.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join comparisons like that. You can:

```
if age == '1' or age == '2' or age == '3':
```

or use the `in` operator as JuniorCompressor suggested.